# Scikit-Learn cross validation with two inputs, one output

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I'm building a CNN model to catagorise data, and am looking at cross validation with Scikit-Learn. I'm using two inputs, and would like to know how to cross validate with two inputs.

From what I can see it only accepts an X input and y output, and have tried using a list of inputs but they are read as a single list.

I've used the following code to iterate through one model and cross validate it, however I don't see any way of cross validating with two inputs.

```
np.random.seed(seed)
kfold = StratifiedKfold(n_splits=10m shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
for train, test in kfold.split(x, y):
  input = Input(shape=(100, 150, 1))
  dense = Dense(2, activation='relu')(input)
  output = Dense(1, activation='relu')(dense)
  model = Model(input, output)
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
  scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
  print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
  cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores), numpy.std(cvscores)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda late but hopefully it will be useful for someone having the same problem.

One possible solution is to concatenate both inputs and then split them accordingly once inside the loop.

As an example:

I already concatenated both inputs into 'x_agg', the first input has 2001 columns.

```
for train_index, valid_index in kfold.split(x_agg, y):
        X_train_fold = x_agg[train_index]
        X_valid_fold = x_agg[valid_index]
        y_train_fold = y[train_index]
        y_valid_fold = y[valid_index]

        x_train_global = X_train_fold[0:, :2001] # Split First Input (Training)
        x_train_local = X_train_fold[0:, 2001:]  
        x_valid_global = X_valid_fold[0:, :2001] # Split First Input (Validation)
        x_valid_local = X_valid_fold[0:, 2001:]

    model.fit([x_train_global, x_train_local], y_train_fold,...]
    score = model.evaluate([x_valid_global, x_valid_local], y_valid_fold, verbose=0)[1]
```